# NServiceBus SqlTransport - Unable to resolve message type for sending

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus5

**UPDATE**
I found the problem. I was not inheriting from ICommand so I added the convention however now i am receiving the following exception:

> The destination queue 'Reimbursement' could not be found. You may have
>   misconfigured the destination for this kind of message
>   (Reimbursement.Messages.Commands.RequestForReimbursementCommand,
>   Reimbursement.Messages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null) in the MessageEndpointMappings of the
>   UnicastBusConfig section in your configuration file. It may also be
>   the case that the given queue just hasn't been created yet, or has
>   been deleted.

I am evaluating NServiceBus for our company using the SqlTransport and I am running into a configuration issue.

Here is my app.config for my sender:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
  </configSections>
  <MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error" />  
  <startup> 
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="NServiceBus/Outbox" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add
      name="NServiceBus/Transport"
      connectionString="Data Source=INLS-03466\ANABOLIC; Initial Catalog=CMS; Integrated Security=True;"/>
    <add
      name="NServiceBus/Persistence"
      connectionString="Data Source=INLS-03466\ANABOLIC; Initial Catalog=CMS; Integrated Security=True;"/>
    <add
      name="NServiceBus/Transport/Reimbursement"
      connectionString="Data Source=INLS-03466\ANABOLIC; Initial Catalog=Reimbursement; Integrated Security=True;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Assembly="Reimbursement.Messages" Endpoint="Reimbursement" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
</configuration>
```

When I go to send the command I receive the following exception:

> No destination could be found for message type
>   Reimbursement.Messages.Commands.RequestForReimbursementCommand. Check
>   the  section of the configuration of this
>   endpoint for an entry either for this specific message type or for its
>   assembly.

The sender references the Reimbursement.Messages assembly so I’m not sure why it is unable to resolve this.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message `The destination queue '*' could not be found.` usually happens when a service wants to subscribe to a publisher but the publishes has not been run yet so that it has created its queues.

An endpoint only creates its own queues but not the queues it subscribes to or the queues of other services to which is sends messages.

The message `No destination could be found for message type` usually happens when there is no destination defined in the configuration, there is no match on message convention or it does not inherit the correct interface (`ICommand`, `IEvent` or `IMessage`).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but i removed/re-added my reference to the external Messages project and it seems to be working now.